# Cannot read property left of undefined. Jquery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am working on reactjs. I am getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (DummyPlayer.js:184)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (dll.vendor.js:39569)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (dll.vendor.js:39381)
```

Below is my code

```
return (

            <div>
                <div className='video-player'>
                    <div className='video-player-inner'>
                        <video
                            className='video-js video-el vjs-big-play-centered vjs-default-skin'
                            id='video-el'
                            ref={node => this.video_el = node}>
                            <source src={this.props.video_file_selected_reducer.url} type="video/mp4"/>
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="custom-seekbar" onClick={this.customBarClicked}>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
```

And this is my customBarClicked method

```
customBarClicked(e){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var left = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var totalWidth = $("#custom-seekbar").width();
       var percentage = ( left / totalWidth );
        var vidTime = duration * percentage;
        currentTime = vidTime;
    }
```

Can someone please tell me the how to solve it?

Comment: By the error message, i'd say `offset` is undefined. Are you sure you're not supposed to be using `e` rather than `this` to target the clicked element?

Comment: I tried $(e).offset(); also. Same error.

Comment: If you do `console.log(e)` what do you see?

Comment: Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, _dispatchInstances: ReactDOMComponent, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click"…}

Comment: ANd you've been through the [react docs especially handling events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) I assume?

Comment: Marked duplicate shows how to access the clicked element - not exactly the same as yours but should answer your question. You probably just need `var offset = $(e.target).offset()`

Comment: @Jamiec thanks a lot. It worked.